# Color picking implementation

Tags: android, 3d, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on a very simple, yet customizable OpenGL ES 2 rendering engine (I know that stuff like "unity" and "unreal engine" exist, and that reinventing the wheel isn't probably the sanest thing to do, just take it as a given ;-) ).

Now I'm facing object picking: I don't want to do ray-casting and I would like to do color picking instead (**free laughs here:** I'm using MRTs on ES3 in the current implementation. *It works, but only where it works*, if you catch my drift...).

AFAIK when color picking, you can either have two buffers (one for selection and one for rendering), or write twice to the same one: each approach has it's pro and cons.

Assuming that I have an *unknown number of objects* is it better:

- to create two buffers and draw each object to each buffer, before going to the next one (thus minimizing the amount of uniforms you have to load, but switching buffer twice for each object)
- to create a single buffer, draw all objects for selection, doing the color picking, then draw everything for rendering (thus limiting the context switching, but increasing program switching and uniforms loading)

I think that the question can be summarized as: *"is it more expensive to switch buffers repetitively, or to switch programs and load uniforms"*?

Oh... and feel free to tell me if the question doesn't make sense :)

Comment: This may differ per implementation. A good idea would be to profile your code. When you switch program (and uniforms), some copy to device may swap out some device memory and hamper performance.

Comment: good point (and this is likely what I'll do: I'll pick the simpler solution and then try the other one for some comparisons after a while), unfortunately I'm targeting android, and the implementation will differ from hardware vendor to the other, so I hoped for some experience/insight about "what the best practice" is, if there is any :)

Comment: But remember one thing, when you use MRTs, most of the GPUs support multiple on-chip buffers and there is no switching of buffers and thus writing to multiple buffers at once can be more efficient most of the time.

Comment: That's what I thought (actually "hey! OpenGL ES3 supports MRT without extensions! And I don't need to do content switching, or load uniforms twice! Everything will be super fast **and** super easy!" is what  I thought)..., then you get blank screens on some devices, hard reboots on other. ATM the only "weird" stuff I'm using is MRT, which is why I'm removing it in favor of classic color picking :/

Comment: anyway, I think I can fix the problem with performances (at least for fill-limited devices) by limiting the part of the buffer to draw or using buffers with different sizes (e.g. I could use a selection buffer that's 1/10 of the rendering one, thus making the whole process quite faster...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mobile the number of drawcalls you make is one of the most important performance factor to consider, the driver overhead for each drawcall is generally huge (bigger on Android than IOS in general), so drawing two times the objects will not be good for perf (will use more CPU => cost of driver calls).

If you have no more than 256 different objects then a simple solution without MRT would be to use a RGBA render target (instead RGB) and store the object "ID" in the alpha channel (so as a grayscale color).

Otherwise, you should at all cost avoid switching buffer repetitively, otherwise you will get slow load/store operations (GPU being forced to memcpy the current buffer to "backup it" when switching to a new one, imagine doing that hundreds of time per frame ...)

So to answer your question it cost more to switch buffer repetitively than to switch program and load uniforms.

PS: if you have more than 256 objects you may eventually try to render in "slices" of 256 objects, after each slice you glRead the buffer pixels and check for object selection in the alpha channel then glClear only the alpha and continue to the next slice. But note that this may not be very efficient either because as soon as you want to read the buffer pixels the CPU has to stall, waiting for the GPU to finish rendering so you are breaking CPU/GPU parallelism

Comment: Thank you for the very interesting answer. Just one question: using the alpha channel to save the id of the object seem promising, however doesn't it also means not only that I am limited to 255 objects (255 + a "no object" value), but also that I cannot use blending at all?

Comment: Classic and additive blending will still work without any problem because they do not use the alpha channel of the buffer, they only use buffer rgb color, if you use more complex blending modes it will fail if the blending formula uses DST_ALPHA... Please check the docs about opengl blending formulaes ...

Comment: ok, I clearly forgot some details about how blending works... thank you for the remark: I'll check the documentation (btw, I checked and I'm using only SRC_ALPHA and ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA, that is, classic blending...)!